# I need to transfer 1 million rows over the internet using Web API and JSON

Tags: c#, json, web, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am working on a project where I need to transfer about a million rows from our third party server to our server.

The criteria are

1. I cannot have direct database access.
2. The data should be available on demand and do not want to store the data for a long time locally.
3. I am not allowed to transfer files.

I was thinking of using Web API for this job and transfer the data using JSON. Along side with this I was going to make the service async. I have also look at Signal R and see if that would work. However that would lead me to storing the data locally which is against one of the criteria.

Question is that, is Web API the answer to my problem or is there a better way of achieving the end result.

Comment: aside from the absurd requirement that you transfer 1 million rows of data across the public internet, the question itself is both too broad (has too many possible options and caveats) and a request for software recommendations, which all adds up to this question being unfit for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer (talking about copy) a million of rows from one server to another does not seems correct (I was a little confused by this part of the question).

The SignalR is used to real time communication, the server updates the client everytime the data is change, with this component the communication happens **on change not on demand**.

The Web API (with REST) you could request data **on demand** not only all data, but small portions of this data, and store only the reference on the target server, if you need.

By example, if you have a million of employees you could:

Get all employees:

```
http://example.com/employees
```

Get employees with status active:

```
http://example.com/employees?active=true
```

Get data about a employee with register 9:

```
http://example.com/employees/9
```

Paging, order and query with OData:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2013/02/19/paging-with-asp-net-web-api-odata/

A brief explanation to REST: http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284

Build a web api with ASP:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

SignalR: 
https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Comment: Your comments were really helpful.